# SSL redirection - how does the client know to switch?

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http

I'm trying to set up a Tomcat cluster behind an Apache load balancer. When I go to the load balancer's URL using a browser I get redirected from http to https. When I do the same with curl I don't. I tried to send the `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header with curl but that had no effect on the headers coming back.

I can't figure out which component is doing it. Why do my browsers switch and curl doesn't? Where is the directive coming from?

Comment: please show the curl command you tried

Comment: Take a look https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-redirects